# Which component is using Joomla in their JED?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I want to create a directory same as JED, can someone tell me which extension is using Joomla in their JED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Joomla Extensions Directory was using Mosets Tree which you can find here:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/directory-a-documentation/directory/mosets-tree

However a while back, [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/) were selected to build the new Extensions Directory. This is a custom component (**com_jed**) which is not available to download.

If you want to have a similar sort of Download Directory, have a look at the [File Management](http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/file-management?&start=0) category on JED

Answer (score 3):

They are using extension **com_jed** which is specifically developed for this extension directory.

This extension has been developed by fabrik team.

http://fabrikar.com/